# Are components re-mounted when back-buttoned from its subsequent screen in React Native Android?

Tags: android, react-native

I need to keep the screen updated to the server whenever the user enters the screen so put the AJAX calls in componentDidMount() method. The AJAX was called when navigator.push() to the screen but when it is back-buttoned from its subsequent screen (navigator.pop()). My understanding is that the components are unmounted when navigator pushes to the next screen and re-mounts when going back. Is my understanding mistaken here? Seems like componentDidMount() wasn't called after navigator.pop() from its following screen.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to hack it is to have a condition check for the BackAndroid callback. For example, by doing a loop through the route stack, if there is the subsequent pages in it, do not call the navigator.pop method. This way, the back button listener only works in the page where they are added and its affiliated drawer pages .

Answer (score 2):

The component is not unmounted when moving forward in the stack (adding routes). For what you are looking to do you will need to have a single component listening to didfocus or willfocus and check the route that is about to display in the callback.

Docs:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#content

Example usage:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Examples/UIExplorer/Navigator/NavigationBarSample.js